# Pandas one row pitvot table returns a serie instead of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Depends on user input we generate pandas pivot table. There is one special case, that in columns is only one attribute. This generate data object of type series as a result of pivot table instead a data frame, so I have to access it in different way (IE. below). Is there some way, how to get same result independently of count of attributes in columns?

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'attr1': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 14}, 'attr2': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2},'metric1': {0: 3834557.25999999998, 1: 13251194.440, 2: 2868778.53}, 'metric2': {0: 7.2, 1: 4.0, 2: 7.5}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

tab1 = df.pivot_table(index=[], columns=["attr1"], values=['metric1', 'metric2'])  
if isinstance(tab1, pd.Series):
    tab1 = pd.DataFrame(tab1).T

print tab1.index
print tab1.columns
print tab1

tab2 = df.pivot_table(index=[], columns=["attr1",'attr2'], values=['metric1','metric2'])  
if isinstance(tab2, pd.Series):
    tab2 = pd.DataFrame(tab2).T
print tab2.index
print tab2.columns
print tab2
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that pandas 0.18 has a [`pd.Series.to_frame` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html). So, you could use

```
 df\
    .pivot_table(
         index=[], 
         columns=["attr1",'attr2'], 
         values=['metric1','metric2'])\
    .to_frame()
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I like your answer as well - plenty of organizations that won't upgrade for a while.

Comment: Series have had the `to_frame` method for a while now.

Comment: @PaulH Interesting. I guess I became aware of it just with this version, then.

Comment: v0.13 is the oldest mention of it that I can find in the docs. Makes me wonder what I'm missing now.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html?highlight=to_frame#pandas.Series.to_frame

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?

```
In [39]: df.pivot_table(index=[], columns=["attr1",'attr2'], values=['metric1','metric2']).reset_index()
Out[39]:
   level_0  attr1  attr2            0
0  metric1      1      1  13251194.44
1  metric1      2      0   3834557.26
2  metric1     14      2   2868778.53
3  metric2      1      1         4.00
4  metric2      2      0         7.20
5  metric2     14      2         7.50
```